# check if jQuery UI easing methods are available

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, plugins, easing

I writing a plugin that does some toggling and I need a way to check what easing methods are available. I want to support the jQuery UI [easing methods](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) when available. It looks like those are in the effects package in the [custom builder](http://jqueryui.com/download) but, since that could be unchecked, it doesn't seem sufficient to check that jQuery UI is available. I want to check specifically that the easing methods are available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can check it this way:

```
if ( $.easing && $.easing.easeInOutQuad ) {
    // Use easing function easeInOutQuad
} else {
    // Use some other stuff
}
```

See from line `597` in UI core (<s>http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.effects.core.js</s>) .

Link it broken but it should still work.

Comment: Nice find—this got me thinking in the right direction. See my response below for what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think I'm going to use:

```
function verifyEasing(input) { 
    return 'linear' === input || ($.easing && $.easing.hasOwnProperty(input)) ? input : false; 
}
```

If the input is `'linear'` or if it's available from jQuery UI then it will return it. Otherwise it will return `false`. I did it like that b/c if you pass `false` as the `.toggle()` easing value then it will default to `'swing'`—hence no need to check for `swing` specifically. Like this:

```
$('.target').toggle( 800, verifyEasing(input) );
```

I guess if you want to check for custom easing functions too then you could add an `$.isFunction` check to the boolean:

```
'linear' === input || ($.easing && $.easing.hasOwnProperty(input)) || $.isFunction(input)
```

Comment: Instead of returning false i would return `null` - late comment :)